# ionic 4 beta No installed build tools found

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m trying to compile android apk, but I get the error “No installed build tools found.”

```
$ ionic cordova build android
```

**Error:**

```
...
Android Studio project detected
Preparing Firebase on Android
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/ubuntu/lapp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 68

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
/home/ubuntu/lapp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/ubuntu/lapp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 68

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

**Environment Variables:**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

$ echo $PATH
...
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:
/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:
/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/tools:
/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/build-tools:
/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:
/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/emulator
```

.

```
$ ionic info

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.6.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-rc.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.11.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.1.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.2

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
   Cordova Platforms     : not available
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.14.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Linux 4.15
```

**I try:**

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

After all this, I installed all the SDKs from Android 4.3 and all Android SDK build-tools from 19.0.3, but even this did not help.

Ps: No matter how I try to set the path to ANDROID_HOME (~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc), but still takes ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1) Terminal as root

`$ sudo -s`

2) Add path to `~/.bash_profile` or  `~/.bashrc`

3) Done!